# Fastest way to determine if two strings differ by an adjacent character swap? C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am writing a C++ algorithm that works very close to determining Damerau–Levenshtein distance, but in 3 sections.
In other words, Damerau–Levenshtein distance returns a cost to get from string A to string B using 
1. deletion/insertion "apple" to "aple" and vice versa
2. substitution of a character "rock" to "rack"
3. swapping of adjacent characters "art" to "rat"

However, the algorithm I am writing must determine if string A can morph into string B using any combination of the above three conditions.

Any advice on how to determine Damerau–Levenshtein distance in 3 different pieces?

Comment: "3 sections"  or "three conditions"  or "3 different pieces" ? presumably you meant the same thing in all those terms, which are all inaccurate and incorrect.  Why not just say "three steps" ?   engilsh much ?

Answer (score 3):

This to me looks like another kind of a problem that can be easily solved by using the [rubber duck development and debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) method. Get your rubber duck, or go out and buy one, if you don't already have it; then sit it down in front of your monitor, and explain to your rubber duck how you would go about testing each one of the three transformations on your list.

The rubber duck approach is real easy! I'll give an example myself, for the 2nd transformation on your list: whether two words are different only by a substitution of one character.

...

Ok, I have my rubber duck now sitting on next to my monitor, and I'm going to explain to my rubber duck how would I figure out if two words differ only in substitution of one character. And you can listen along, while I'm speaking:

1) Ok, the first thing I would do, Mr. Duck, is verify that both words have the same number of characters. If they're not, I don't need to go any further. Because the words differ in number of characters they can't be different only by a single character's substitution, which does not change the number of characters in a word. You see, Mr. Duck, this means that both words must have the same exact number of characters. If they don't it means that my two words must be different in some other way, other than a single character substitution.

2) Ok, now I know the two words are of the same length. The next thing, I would do is check whether the first character of both words are the same. Then, I'll check whether the second character of both words are the same, and so on, until I check every pair of corresponding characters from each word. Then, I simply need to keep track of how many times I saw a different pair of characters, all the while through. If I saw only one pair of different characters, it must mean, Mr. Duck, that there was example one pair of different characters -- no more, and no less -- so the first word can be transformed into the second word by changing just one character.

[ I put my rubber duck back in storage now ]

See how easy it was? Don't you see how easy it is, now, to write a few lines of code, based on the detailed, step by step algorithm that I've explained to my rubber duck, above? The words practically translate themselves into code!

You can do this too! Go take your rubber duck, put it in front of your monitor, and explain to your rubber duck how you would go about testing the other two potential transformations on your list.

And finally, after having explaining to your rubber duck how to check each one of the possible three transformation, given a pair of words, you can finish your tale by explaining to your attentive rubber duck how now you can answer the very question you asked, yourself.